# my dell 20.5" screen has a red, vertical bar about 2" wide, is the monitor trash?

Tags: display, lcd

As of about 1 hour ago, my Dell 20.5" monitor has a 2" vertical red bar on the screen.

It is a 4 year old LCD. Does this mean the monitor is effectively ruined or is this something that can be fixed somehow?

Comment: Now you have an excuse to upgrade to a larger one!

Answer (score 3):

There may be a loose connection in the LCD that is causing this, but chance are that it is toast...

Comment: I did check the connections, so unfort. it doesn't seem to be the case.